# convert a string date and time in miliseconds

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to set alarm .but my date and time are stored in db.when i will get these they are in string. when i will get date and time and it looks like this:

10:33 AM4/11/2015

Please tell me how I can convert this in milliseconds.and I am new here please ignore the problems in question posting.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
        ShoppingListItem item = new ShoppingListItem();
        item.setCategory(names.get(i).getCategory());
        item.setTitleName(names.get(i).getTitle());
        item.setTimeVal(names.get(i).getTime());
        item.setCalender(names.get(i).getCalendar());
        item.setAddres(names.get(i).getAddress());
        item.setDb_row_id(names.get(i).getDb_row_id());
        //item.setColorImage(names);
        mAdapter.addItem(item);
        String s = names.get(i).getTime() + names.get(i).getCalendar();
        System.out.println("GetTime"+s);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the formatted string date. 
Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aaMM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = sdformat.parse(your-string-date);
long milliseconds = date.getTime(); //<--here gets the milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code

```
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();

// offset to add since we're not UTC

long offset = rightNow.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) +
    rightNow.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);

long sinceMidnight = (rightNow.getTimeInMillis() + offset) %
    (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

System.out.println(sinceMidnight + " milliseconds since midnight")
```